# Cereal Library static_assert failed 'cereal could not find any output serialization functions for the provided type and archive combination.'

Tags: c++, serialization, sfml, cereal

I am trying to serialize SFML shapes for a 2D ms paint like program. I am getting an assertion error during build but everything online I can find it is a result of not marking a function with the template class. Here is the only place in my code where I am ussing the library, can someone help me find my issue? Thank you!

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cereal/cereal.hpp>

namespace cereal {

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, sf::Vector2f& vector) {
        ar(CEREAL_NVP(vector.x), CEREAL_NVP(vector.y));
    }

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, sf::RectangleShape& shape) {
        sf::Vector2f position = shape.getPosition();
        sf::Vector2f size = shape.getSize();
        sf::Color fillColor = shape.getFillColor();
        sf::Color outlineColor = shape.getOutlineColor();
        float outlineThickness = shape.getOutlineThickness();

        ar(CEREAL_NVP(position), CEREAL_NVP(size), CEREAL_NVP(fillColor), CEREAL_NVP(outlineColor), CEREAL_NVP(outlineThickness));

        shape.setPosition(position);
        shape.setSize(size);
        shape.setFillColor(fillColor);
        shape.setOutlineColor(outlineColor);
        shape.setOutlineThickness(outlineThickness);
    }

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, sf::CircleShape& circle) {
        std::size_t pointCount = circle.getPointCount();
        sf::Vector2f position = circle.getPosition();
        float radius = circle.getRadius();
        sf::Color fillColor = circle.getFillColor();
        sf::Color outlineColor = circle.getOutlineColor();
        float outlineThickness = circle.getOutlineThickness();

        ar(CEREAL_NVP(position), CEREAL_NVP(radius), CEREAL_NVP(fillColor), CEREAL_NVP(outlineColor), CEREAL_NVP(outlineThickness));

        circle.setPointCount(pointCount);
        circle.setPosition(position);
        circle.setRadius(radius);
        circle.setFillColor(fillColor);
        circle.setOutlineColor(outlineColor);
        circle.setOutlineThickness(outlineThickness);
    }
}

template void cereal::serialize<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive&, sf::Vector2f&);
template void cereal::serialize<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive&, sf::RectangleShape&);
template void cereal::serialize<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive&, sf::CircleShape&);
```

Here is the output log:

```
Build started at 7:21 PM...
1>------ Build started: Project: Simple2D-DrawingApplication, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>DrawingDataSaver.cpp
1>D:\Dev\LocalRepos\Simple2D-DrawingApplication\Src\SFMLSerialization.h(51,112): warning C4667: 'void cereal::serialize(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive &,sf::RectangleShape &)': no function template defined that matches forced instantiation
1>D:\Dev\LocalRepos\Simple2D-DrawingApplication\Src\SFMLSerialization.h(52,109): warning C4667: 'void cereal::serialize(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive &,sf::CircleShape &)': no function template defined that matches forced instantiation
1>D:\Dev\LocalRepos\Simple2D-DrawingApplication\cereal-1.3.2\include\cereal\cereal.hpp(570,87): error C2338: static_assert failed: 'cereal could not find any output serialization functions for the provided type and archive combination.
1> Types must either have a serialize function, load/save pair, or load_minimal/save_minimal pair (you may not mix these).
1> Serialize functions generally have the following signature:
1> template<class Archive>
1>   void serialize(Archive & ar)
1>   {
1>     ar( member1, member2, member3 );
1>   }
1> '
1>D:\Dev\LocalRepos\Simple2D-DrawingApplication\cereal-1.3.2\include\cereal\cereal.hpp(444,13): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'ArchiveType &cereal::OutputArchive<ArchiveType,1>::processImpl<std::shared_ptr<sf::Shape>,(cereal::traits::detail::sfinae)0>(const T &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            ArchiveType=cereal::BinaryOutputArchive,
1>            T=std::shared_ptr<sf::Shape>
1>        ]
1>D:\Dev\LocalRepos\Simple2D-DrawingApplication\cereal-1.3.2\include\cereal\cereal.hpp(333,13): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void cereal::OutputArchive<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive,1>::process<const std::shared_ptr<sf::Shape>&>(T)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=const std::shared_ptr<sf::Shape> &
1>        ]
1>D:\Dev\LocalRepos\Simple2D-DrawingApplication\Src\DrawingDataSaver.cpp(19,3): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'ArchiveType &cereal::OutputArchive<ArchiveType,1>::operator ()<const std::shared_ptr<sf::Shape>&>(const std::shared_ptr<sf::Shape> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            ArchiveType=cereal::BinaryOutputArchive
1>        ]
1>D:\Dev\LocalRepos\Simple2D-DrawingApplication\Src\DrawingDataSaver.cpp(19,10): message : see the first reference to 'cereal::OutputArchive<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive,1>::operator ()' in 'DrawingDataSaver::Save'
1>DrawingApp.cpp
1>D:\Dev\LocalRepos\Simple2D-DrawingApplication\Src\SFMLSerialization.h(51,112): warning C4667: 'void cereal::serialize(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive &,sf::RectangleShape &)': no function template defined that matches forced instantiation
1>D:\Dev\LocalRepos\Simple2D-DrawingApplication\Src\SFMLSerialization.h(52,109): warning C4667: 'void cereal::serialize(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive &,sf::CircleShape &)': no function template defined that matches forced instantiation
1>D:\Dev\LocalRepos\Simple2D-DrawingApplication\Src\SFMLSerialization.h(10,3): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
1>D:\Dev\LocalRepos\Simple2D-DrawingApplication\Src\SFMLSerialization.h(50,23): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void cereal::serialize<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive &,sf::Vector2f &)' being compiled
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "Simple2D-DrawingApplication.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 7:21 PM and took 05.360 seconds ==========
```

Comment: please show the full compiler output

Comment: This is why we ask for a [mre]. The error is about `std::shared_ptr<sf::Shape>` which you've not provided a serialisation function for. If you're trying to do this polymorphically you'll need to read the documentation https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/polymorphism.html